# why does laravel ignore my update method?

Tags: laravel

I've an update function for my `Gamecontroller` but it gets completely ignored when I call it and it just redirects to show view instead of executing the function despite calling it, am I missing something obvious?

Things I know and tried:

- Every other function works in the `GameController`
- I tried calling other functions like `game.create` and `game.delete` from that same view so I doubt it has to do with my view
- I tried making the validate fail which got ignored because the function somehow doesn't get called
- I tried just commenting the entire function and it did nothing didn't even give an error like it should
- Checked to see if there was somehow a double function (there wasn't)

My update function in `GameController` class

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'naam' => 'required|max:1',
            'img' => 'required',
            'formaat' => 'required',
            'datum' => 'required',
            'locatie' => 'required',
        ]);

        if($validated->fails()){
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validated);
        }

        DB::table('games')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->update([
                'naam' => $request->naam,
                'img' => $request->img,
                'formaat' => $request->formaat,
                'datum' => $request->datum,
                'locatie' => $request->locatie,
            ]);

        return Redirect::to('games')
            ->with('success','Great! game updated successfully.');
    }
```

My view:

```
        <form action="{{ route('games.update',$data->id) }}" method="PUT" name="edit_games">
        @csrf
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Naam</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="naam" class="form-control" value= "{{ $data->naam }}" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Pad van de afbeelding</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="img" class="form-control" value="{{$data->img}}" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Formaat</strong>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="formaat" value="{{$data->formaat}}" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Datum</strong>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="datum" value={{$data->datum}}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Locatie</strong>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="locatie" value="{{$data->locatie}}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
```

The route in web

```
    Route::resource('/games', 'GameController');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML Forms can only have `GET` or `POST` method used. You have defined the method attribute as `PUT`: `method="PUT"`; this will end up using the `GET` method, which would end you up at your `show` route. Change your `method` attribute to `POST` then add a hidden field named `_method` with the desired HTTP method (`PUT`) in your case. (Form method spoofing)

```
<form method="POST" ....>
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

`method_field('PUT')` will end up putting a hidden input into your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Routing - Form Method Spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Comment: thx a lot completely forgot about the fact that HTML forms can only have get or post